# Concatenate Arrays as String with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

i have two array ($a , $b) which holds the following strings:

**$a**

```
MSSQL11.SQLINST15
MSSQL12.SQLINST16
MSSQL12.SQLINST17
```

**$b**

```
2874
2884
2885
```

That i'm trying to concatenate to a new array ($c), as a strings with a comma sign in the middle:

**$c**

```
MSSQL11.SQLINST15,2874
MSSQL12.SQLINST16,2884
MSSQL12.SQLINST17,2885
```

Problem is, that using my current ps code:

```
$c = @($a + ',' + $b)
[string]::Concat($c) 
$c
```

I'm getting a very strange output:

```
MSSQL11.SQLINST15
MSSQL12.SQLINST16
MSSQL12.SQLINST17
,
2887
2884
2885
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this way of doing it. Create a zip function to combine your two arrays into a single array of tuples.

Then it's just a matter of piping piece-wise over that tuple list our zip function gives us. Super convenient and reusable.

```
function Zip($a, $b) {
    while ($a) {
        $x, $a = $a
        $y, $b = $b
        [tuple]::Create($x, $y)
    }
}
$c = zip $a $b |% {$_.item1 + [string]$_.item2}
```

Note you can choose where ya wanna to your [string] conversion (in the following, the last line of zip).

```
function Zip($a, $b) {
    while ($a) {
        $x, $a = $a
        $y, $b = $b
        [tuple]::Create([string]$x, $y)
    }
}
$c = zip $a $b |% {$_.item1 + $_.item2}
```

Extra info: Looks like you're accidentally just combining the two arrays using a ",". But $a and $b are arrays, so what you actually want to do is combine the first element of $a with the first element of $b (aka `$a[0] + [string]$b[0]`, and so on for each element. Why the [0]? Remember we almost always start counting at 0 in programming. So the second item of an array is actually [1].

Edit: Here is an example using a foreach loop.
```

```
foreach($item in $a) {
  $i = $a.IndexOf($item)
  $a[$i] + [string]$b[$i]
}
```

```

If for some reason $a has 10 things in it, and $b only has 2 things, it's gonna give you funny behavior.  So be careful there. Please let me know if I can better clarify anything. Don't forget to experiment.

Comment: as you mentioned,  what i'm trying to do is to combine the first element of $a with the first element of $b and with a comma sign and so on.. but i and didn't understand you..do i need to use the zip function you wrote? or as your wrote in the end of your answer ($c = $a[0] + [string]$b[0]) just in a for each condition instead ?..

Comment: You could define/use the zip function (especially if you might want to do the same kind of task again elsewhere in your code--you can reuse the zip function). Otherwise, you can do it using a foreach (see my edit with foreach example)

Answer (score 0):

At the end, i've use a powershell hashtable.